# Service Account unable to access BQ Query results initiated by AppEng

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

My cloud functions, CF (using service account credentials,  `SERVICE-ACCOUNT@PROJECT-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com`) is unable to fetch BQ query results, when query is initiated on app running on AppEngine (using App Engine Default service account credentials, `PROJECT-ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`)

> File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 293, in api_request raise exceptions.from_http_response(response) google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/[PROJECT]/queries/[BQ-JOB-ID]?maxResults=0: Access Denied:Dataset [TEMP-DATASET-ID-STORING-QUERY-RESULTS]: The user [SERVICE-ACCOUNT-EMAIL] does not have permission to access results of another user's job.
>   ```

The whole thing has 2 parts (everything using PY3.x Client Libraries)

**PART A**: running on AppEng Flexible env. (Py3.x) initiates a BQ query `job.insert`. The request ends by publishing this job_id to Pubsub topic.

**PART B**: A Cloud function (python37 runtime, triggering on this Pubsub event):

- **STEP1**: receives this query job_id in `PubsubMessage`
- **STEP2**: checks the query status until DONE, `job.done`
- **STEP3**: when DONE retrieves the query results
- **STEP4**: after query result is fetched, do the final processing (at-least that’s the intention)

On STEP4 I’m getting above mentioned error (obtained rrom Stackdriver Logging)

I acknowledge even though the

- job owner `PROJECT-ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`
- and, query results consumer `SERVICE-ACCOUNT@PROJECT-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

are different, but both Google Account emails have Project Edit level permissions, and thus expected CF to be able to access the query Job results! More so, when CF (using Service Account credentials) are able to pass STEP2 (job.get, polling job status until it’s DONE), it's only the retrieval of query result (STEP4) is throwing the error

Any guidance will be highly appreciable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running job and consuming results with different identities, persist the results to a named destination table.  You can setup a designated dataset with a short TTL so tables are automatically removed after that time.  Cached/anonymous results are by default restricted to the query creator.

An example of constructing a query with a destination table [can be found in the BigQuery docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#writing_query_results).

Comment: Thanks a lot! FEEBACK: it'd be good to document somewhere on the site that only the query job owner has access to query results table.. (or is it already? I couldn't locate...). I spent hours playing around with service account's IAM permissions and wondering why EVEN giving Editor access keeps returning Permission Denied error :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  There's a doc about [cached results](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results#how_cached_results_are_stored), but the exclusive permission aspect could be clearer.  I'll see about getting that clarified.

Comment: @shollyman I ran into the same. When you say " Cached/anonymous results are by default restricted to the query creator", can that be changed so that the project owner has access to the dataset, considering "he has full access to all resources" ?